# How to send and receive a binary tree using MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

I want to send a binary tree from one core to another use some function
like MPI_Send(). Or do there have any fast algorithm to make this function?

The data structure I use is

```
typedef struct BiNode{
    struct BiNode *lchi,*rchi;
    struct BiNode *parent;
    char *name;
}BiNode;
```

This binary tree have more than 2000 leaves.

Comment: Please describe the data structure you want to send more clearly - **with code** ([mcve]). It's best if you add what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I had changed this. Thanks for your remind.

Comment: First concentrate on ex. how to save and load it to a file. You have to loose pointers. Basically you have to write a way to serialize and deserialize your data.

Comment: How often do you need to transmit such 2000-leaves trees?

Answer (score 2):

Read more about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). A 2000 nodes tree is, on current machines and networks, quite a small piece of data. If the average name length is a dozen of bytes, you need to transmit a few dozens of kilobytes (not a big deal today). Typical datacenter network bandwidth is 100Mbytes/sec, and [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (using e.g. some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) or [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) between cores of the same processor) is usually at least ten times faster. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html

> Or do there have any fast algorithm to make this function?

You probably need some [depth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) traversal (and there is probably nothing faster).

You might consider writing your tree in some textual format -or some [text-based protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol)- such as (some customized variant using) [JSON](https://json.org/) (or XML or YAML or [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)). Then take advantage of existing JSON libraries, such as [Jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/). They are capable of encoding and decoding your data (in some JSON format) in a dynamically allocated string buffer.

If performance is critical, consider using some binary format, like [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or [ASN-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). Or simply compress the JSON (or other textual) encoding, using some existing compression library (perhaps [zlib](https://zlib.net/)).

My guess is that in your case, it is not worth the trouble (using JSON is a lot simpler to code, and your development time has some cost and value). Your bottleneck is probably the network itself, not any software layers. But you need to benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

MPI has a feature called datatypes. A full explanation would take a *really* long time, but you probably want to look at structs in there (though you might be able to get away with vectors depending on how your memory is laid out).

However, you probably can't just use MPI datatypes because you'd just be transmitting a bunch of pointers which won't mean anything to the process on the other end. Instead you have to decide which parts you actually need to send and serialize them in a way that makes sense.

So you have a few options I think.

1. Change the way your tree is laid out in memory so it's an array of contiguous memory where all of the pointers you have above become indices in the array.

   - This might not actually make sense in the context of your application, but it makes the "tree" very easy to transmit. At that point, you can either just send a large array of bytes or you can construct MPI datatypes to describe each cell in the array and send an array of 2000 of those.
2. Re-create the tree on the other process from the source data (whether that's a file or something else).

   - This is probably not the answer you were looking for and doesn't help if you've generated this data from anything non-trivial in the middle of your application.
3. Use POSIX shared memory.

   - Since you say "core" in the description of your question, I'm assuming you want to transfer data between OS processes on the same physical machine. If that's the case, you can use shared memory and you don't need to do message passing at all. Just open a shared memory region, attach to it with the other process and "poof" all of the data is available on the other end. As long as you share all of the memory that those pointers are pointing to, I think you'll be fine.